# Locate All YouTube iFrames by source

Tags: jquery, regex, iframe

I am attempting to modify the [Fluid Width YouTube Videos script by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/) to bring it up to date. I am having a few issues with the regex.

This regex works:

- `$("iframe[src^='https://www.youtube-nocookie.com']")`

This regex does not work:

- `$("iframe[src^='\s*(https?://www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com/(?:v|embed)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*)']")`

The later validates, so I assume this is an issue with how I am placing it into the JS.

What is the correct way to find iframe source based on regex?

HTML:

```
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="video-container small">
      <iframe class="video youtube" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/4mBqT7RcEyM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen width="530" height="298"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stripe {
        display:table;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
    }
.container {
    max-width:100%;
        margin:15px auto;
        padding:15px 50px;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
.video-container {
        max-width:530px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    // Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='\s*(https?://www.youtube(?:-nocookie)?.com/(?:v|embed)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*)']"),

        // The element that is fluid width
        $fluidEl = $(".video-container");

    // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
    $allVideos.each(function() {

        $(this)
            .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

            // and remove the hard coded width/height
            .removeAttr('height')
            .removeAttr('width');

    });

    // When the window is resized
    // (You'll probably want to debounce this)
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

        // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
        $allVideos.each(function() {

            var $el = $(this);
            $el
                .width(newWidth)
                .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

        });

    // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
    }).resize();

});
```

[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ubbq08g4/1/)

Comment: `[attr^=value]` => *Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given **string**.* I don't think regex will work on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^=` is a "starts with" jQuery selector, not a regular expression selector.

The simplest way to achieve this is to select all `iframe` elements and `.filter` them by `src`.

```
var $allVideos = $('iframe').filter(function() {
  return this.src.match(/\s*(https?:\/\/www.youtube(?:-nocookie).com\/(?:v|embed)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).*)/);
});
```